# Checking a Dataflow job (async) status using the Java SDK

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

According to the Dataflow [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params), there are 2 ways to run a Dataflow pipeline/job in the cloud:

1. Synchronous  (`BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner`)
2. Asynchronous (`DataflowPipelineRunner`)

When using synchronous, it will of course block and return the `PipelineResult` when the job finishes. That's fine.

But what if I want to check the status of the job while it's running asynchronously? I'd like to:

1. Run the job asynchronously i.e. use `DataflowPipelineRunner`
2. Poll the job for its status, and check how long it's been running
3. If it's been running too long then raise an alaram

Polling the [status of the job is possible](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dataflow-command-line-intf) with the `gcloud` command line tool. However, how can this be done programatically via the Java SDK (REST api)? I cannot see any methods that would facilitate this.

The motivation for this is that we had a job hang, and we did not realise until 11 hours after it was kicked off. It usually takes 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the same APIs that the `BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner` uses.

The method [`DataflowPipelineRunner#run`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/runners/DataflowPipelineRunner#run-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline-) returns a [`DataflowPipelineJob`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/runners/DataflowPipelineJob). The method [`DataflowPipelineJob#getState`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/runners/DataflowPipelineJob#getState--) will let you check the current state of the job. You may also interrogate aggregators via [`DataflowPipelineJob#getAggregatorValues`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/runners/DataflowPipelineJob#getAggregatorValues-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.Aggregator-). (The `BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner` uses the convenience method [`DataflowPipelineJob#waitToFinish`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/runners/DataflowPipelineJob#waitToFinish-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.MonitoringUtil.JobMessagesHandler-) instead of doing the polling itself)

Comment: Can I only get the state e.g. RUNNING, DONE etc.? Or is it possible to also get more information like what's available using the command line gcloud tool e.g. creation_time, job_name etc.